# Windows 10 Mist reinstall

Tags: mist

I flattened my pc and then reinstalled Mist it now asks me to open a "new" account. I want to reinstall my old one... how do I do it? I am currently downloading chsindata. I have my JSON files etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can add/remove accounts by copying the json file directly to the geth keystore directory in **C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\keystore**

Once done, just restart Mist and you should be able to see your account.